# Python, communicating variables between a script and .exe

Tags: python, variables, input, executable

I have a python script: **main.py**, which executes a cx_frozen python script: **test.exe** I have created. main.py needs to send variables to test.exe. If the frozen script is able to send variables back that would be great too.

I have, up to this point been saving out .txt files from main.py and accepting them from test.exe side. But now that I am introducing multithreading, I am concerned the instances of test.exe will collect information from the .txts intended for other instances of test.exe.

I was wondering if this is possible? How do I tell **main.py** to send variables to **test.exe** accept them ... and, if possible, send them back to main.py

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to send variables to a sub-program is using command line arguments or environment variables.  If you want bidirectional communication you can use pipes to transmit the info that you are currently sending over the text files (even on Windows).  The python `subprocess` (http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) module is very good at that that sort of thing.

Comment: thanks, I am infact using subprocess to open test.exe but I didn't realize it was capable of this. I'm also not sure how I would go about altering test.exe in order to accept variables. I'll read up on subprocess and hopefully that will help

Comment: Ok, if you can't modify test.exe then you options are limited.  But apart from the, subprocess is pretty powerful, and worth reading about carefully.

Comment: I can modify test.exe ... I'm just not sure what needs modifying. Can I just start it prompting for a raw_input?

Comment: I would just use read sys.stdin, e.g. iterate with `for line in sys.stdin : ... parse "line" ...`